# Pandas add a new column based on conditional logic of many other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
aa bb cc dd ee
a  a  b  b  foo
a  b  a  a  foo
b  a  a  a  bar
b  b  b  b  bar
```

I want to add a new column if value in columns 1 to 4 is `a`

The results would be like this:

```
aa bb cc dd ee  ff
a  a  b  b  foo a
a  b  a  a  foo a
b  a  a  a  bar a
b  b  b  b  bar b
```

The logic is:
if value in any of columns 1 to 4 is `a` then column `ff` is `a` else it's `b`

I can define a function and do each column manually like:

```
def some_function(row);
   if row['aa']=='a' or row['bb']=='a' or row['cc']=='a' or row[dd]=='a':
       return 'a'
   return 'b'
```

But I'm looking for a solution that can scale across `n` number of columns.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Perhaps you can just use `df.iloc[:,:4].min(1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition created by `eq` (==) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per row:

```
cols = ['aa','bb','cc', 'dd']
df['ff'] = np.where(df[cols].eq('a').any(1), 'a', 'b')
print (df)
  aa bb cc dd   ee ff
0  a  a  b  b  foo  a
1  a  b  a  a  foo  a
2  b  a  a  a  bar  a
3  b  b  b  b  bar  b
```

Detail:

```
print (df[cols].eq('a'))
      aa     bb     cc
0   True   True  False
1   True  False   True
2  False   True   True
3  False  False  False

print (df[cols].eq('a').any(1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

If need custom function:

```
def some_function(row):
   if row[cols].eq('a').any():
       return 'a'
   return 'b'

df['ff'] = df.apply(some_function, 1)
print (df)
  aa bb cc dd   ee ff
0  a  a  b  b  foo  a
1  a  b  a  a  foo  a
2  b  a  a  a  bar  a
3  b  b  b  b  bar  b
```